# Testing for differences between pooled biological samples

Tags: statistical-significance, experiment-design

I am trying to test for differences in absorbance between a control and treatment group.  Due to cost, each measurement is derived from the mixture of 5 independent samples.  Overall there are 5 sample measurements each derived from 5 individual samples.  The data would look like:

```
Control:
Measurement 1 (from 5 combined samples)
Measurement 2 (from 5 combined samples)
Measurement 3 (from 5 combined samples)
etc.

Treatment:
Measurement 1 (from 5 combined samples)
Measurement 2 (from 5 combined samples)
Measurement 3 (from 5 combined samples)
etc.
```

Here my issue is that each measurement would be close to the mean value of the 5 combined samples and we would not know much about the actual variance that would be observed across individual samples.  Because of this I'm thinking that I can't apply a simple test like a t test to test for a difference between groups.

I appreciate any suggestions about how to properly test between the groups using data gathered in this fashion.  Also, would your suggestion work if each measurement was collected from varying numbers of samples?  For example: 3 sample for one measurement, 5 samples for another measurement, 2 samples for another?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'pool'. You say that if $X_{11}, X_{12}, \dots , X_{15}$ are pooled, then the mean of the pooled value $X_1$ is close the the means of the constituent $X_{1j}$s, and that makes me think $X_1$ may be an average. But some of you other statements lead me to guess that pooling isn't just averaging.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean pooling in the statistical sense.  Equal amounts of material from five separate subjects are physically mixed together and one measurement is taken from that mixture.  This site states that mixing samples can improve precision in the case of transcriptomic data and the measurement will represent the mean of the mixed samples.  However, I am confused because I'm thinking that the observed variance will be underestimated when using mean values as replicates instead of measurements from individual samples. [link](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat555/node/75/)

Comment: I think you would be safe treating each pooled observation as a data point and running a two-sample test using five 'observations' in each group. Use a Welch t test if pooled observations seem normal, otherwise Wilcoxon rank sum. For these tests, it is the variability of the pooled observations themselves that matters. // See my answer for hypothetical count data below. If you want to post your actual10 pooled data values, I will have a look at them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is that your 50 original samples are Poisson counts, in which case pooling
would give you 10 pooled samples with somewhat larger Poisson counts---five Control and five Treatment.

Poisson data with reasonably large counts are approximately normal. A difficulty might
be that different population means between the Treatment and Control groups would imply different population variances also. There are two ways to handle potentially different variances in this situation. A traditional approach is to use a square root transformation to 'stabilize' variances. Another would be to use a Welch 2-sample t test, which does not require equal variances. I would prefer the latter.

Maybe your data are something like the simulated data below:

```
set.seed(1126)
x1 = rpois(5, 20)
x2 = rpois(5, 35)
summary(x1); length(x1);  sd(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
     16      23      24      23      26      26 
[1] 5            # sample size
[1] 4.123106     # sample standard deviation

summary(x2); length(x2);  sd(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   25.0    30.0    35.0    33.2    36.0    40.0 
[1] 5
[1] 5.80517

stripchart(list(x1,x2), ylim=c(.5, 2.5), meth="stack", pch=20)
```

[image]

For illustration, here are results from a Welch t test on the counts and a pooled 2-sample t test on square
roots of counts. Both tests find significant differences at the 2% level.
[You should choose *one* test.]

```
t.test(x1, x2)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -3.2032, df = 7.217, p-value = 0.01439
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -17.68411  -2.71589
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
     23.0      33.2 

t.test(sqrt(x1), sqrt(x2), var.eq=T)

         Two Sample t-test

data:  sqrt(x1) and sqrt(x2)
t = -3.1448, df = 8, p-value = 0.01371
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.6726184 -0.2573859
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 4.778570  5.743572
```

*Notes:* (1) For the test on square roots of counts, the confidence interval may be difficult to
interpret. (2) If any counts are $0,$ it is customary to add $0.5$ to all
counts before taking square roots.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I was leaning towards Welch's t-test which I would have used if the measurements were taken from single individual samples.  I was mainly hung up about whether measurements from the physically mixed samples would cause the test to be too permissive.